# mysql update query optimization

Tags: mysql, optimization

I have a database with 200+ entries, and with a cronjob I'm updating the database every 5 minutes. All entries are unique.

My code:

```
for($players as $pl){
   mysql_query("UPDATE rp_players SET state_one = '".$pl['s_o']."', state_two = '".$pl['s_t']."' WHERE id = '".$pl['id']."' ")
   or die(mysql_error());
}
```

There are 200+ queries every 5 minute. I don't know what would happen if my database will have much more entries (2000... 5000+). I think the server will die.

Is there any solution (optimization or something...)?

Comment: solution is to measure the limit. 5k entries/5 minutes should be suitable for any sql server.

Comment: Why don't you start deleting some older entries?

Comment: where do you get the list of players to be updated?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can't do much but make the cron to be executed every 10 minutes if it's getting slower and slower. Also, you can set X rule to delete X days old entries.

Answer (score 0):

If id is your primary (and unique as you mentioned) key, updates should be fast and couldn't be optimised (since it's a primary key... if not, see if you can add an index).

The only problem which could occur (on my mind) is cronjob overlapping, due to slow updates: let's assume your job starts at 1:00am and isn't finished at 1:05am... this will mean that your queries will pile up, creating server load, slow response time, etc...

If this is your case, you should use [rabbitmq](http://www.rabbitmq.com) in order to queue your update queries in order to process them in a more controlled way...

Answer (score 0):

I would load all data that is to be updated into a temporary table using the LOAD DATA INFILE command: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-data.html

Then, you could update everything with one query:

```
UPDATE FROM rp_players p
INNER JOIN tmp_players t
  ON p.id = t.id
SET p.state_one = t.state_one
  , p.state_two = t.state_two
;
```

This would be much more efficient because you would remove a lot of the back and forth to the server that you are incurring by running a separate query every time through a php loop.

Depending on where the data is coming from, you might be able to remove PHP from this process entirely.